# Media Queries don't work when App is opened in phone browser

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

My media queries work for all sizes I have specified when I use the responsive design mode in my browser. These same media queries will not work when I open my web App on a different device. For example, the height I have set for one of my div is: `197px` for screen `max-height: 700px` and `290px` for screen `max-width: 1382px`. When I use responsive web design, the media queries for both sizes work fine. When I resize my browser or open the same web App in my mobile (max-height below 700px), the media query is still rendering for screen width of 1382px.

Similarly media queries do not work when I resize my browser (on my laptop) instead of using responsive design mode.

What I understand is that media queries work on browser window size instead of the device's viewport size. I have tried using both `media all` and ```media screen```` and neither is helping resolve this issue. So, how do I write media queries to support browser window sizes?

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please put enough code into your question so we can see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve the issue:

1. The not so practical way of adding a large number of breakpoints (for both max/min heights and widths). The problem that may arise is the ordering of media queries will get messed up, breaking the layout.
2. Using flexbox/grid at every level of your code. Even a floating menu or any other floating component should be put under a flexbox structure. In which case, you will have to write just the bare minimum number of media queries and the flexbox properties will take care of keeping your layout clean.